# Can I temporarily swap out my new MacBook hard drive with the old one?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, macbook, swap

I recently upgraded my standard hd to an ssd. There are some files on the old one that I still need to access. Can I simply swap the current one for the old one temporarily? Just to email off some files? And then switch back without any issues?

That would be lovely...

Comment: is the kind of macbook with all the components soldered in?

Comment: No, mid 2011 macbook pro. I pulled it out myself, I'll swap it back in temporarily as well. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you did not erase the install and it is as it was when you took it out, you will be fine to do so.

Another option would be to get an external enclosure for the old drive so you can get them off, and then use it as an external storage space afterward.

(That is operating under the assumption that you removed it yourself, and it is a 2.5" hard drive -- ssd swap).   I assume since you suggested you did the swap, it's the standard 2.5" Hard Drive and 2.5" SSD.